# To disable all radio button options on page load if any radio button option is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

So I have a screen with multiple radio buttons. On initial page load, the page with radio button controls needs to be displayed regularly. But if selected and saved, on postback the radio button control needs to be disabled and not able to change. If the radio button control was not selected, then they should appear as normal.

This is my code.

```
<div id="divFood">
   @foreach (var fruit in Model)
   {
       <input id="@fruit.Value" type="radio" name="Fruit" value="@fruit.Value"/>
       <label for="@fruit.Value">@fruit.Text</label>
       <br/>
   }
   @foreach (var dairy in Model.Dairy)
   {
       <input id="@dairy.Value" type="radio" name="Dairy" value="@dairy.Value"/>
       <label for="@dairy.Value">@dairy.Text</label>
       <br/>
   }
   @foreach (var veg in Model.Vegetable)
   {
       <input id="@veg.Value" type="radio" name="Veg" value="@veg.Value"/>
       <label for="@veg.Value">@veg.Text</label>
       <br/>
   }
   @foreach (var meat in Model.Meat)
   {
       <input id="@meat.Value" type="radio" name="Meat" value="@meat.Value"/>
       <label for="@meat.Value">@meat.Text</label>
       <br/>
   }
</div>
```

My JQuery code is as follows. The issue is that my code only disables the selected radio button option rather than the radiobutton control. For example, if in Meat radio button, chicken option is selected, Only chicken gets disabled and not all other options of Meat. How do I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divFood input[type=radio]").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {  
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
        }                       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through *checked* radio button and then inside *each* loop get the **name attribute** of checked radio to disabled other radio with same name.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#divFood input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
    $("input[name=" + $(this).attr('name') + "]").prop("disabled", "true") //disabled
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divFood">
  <input type="radio" name="Fruit" value="A" />
  <label for="@fruit.Value">A</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="Fruit" value="B" checked />
  <label for="@fruit.Value">B</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="Fruit" value="C" />
  <label for="@fruit.Value">C</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="Meat" value="AM" />
  <label for="@meat.Value">AM</label>
  <br/>

  <input type="radio" name="Meat" value="CM" />
  <label for="@meat.Value">CM</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="Meat" value="PM" />
  <label for="@meat.Value">PM</label>
  <br/>

  <input type="radio" name="Veg" value="CMC" checked />
  <label for="@meat.Value">CMC</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="Veg" value="PMC" />
  <label for="@meat.Value">PMC</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="radio" name="Veg" value="PMR" />
  <label for="@meat.Value">PMR</label>
  <br/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used jQuery in too long so unsure how to do it with JQ's `filter` and `each` however with native dom api's you can do something like the following.

First we select all of the inputs, we filter the list by any that are checked. Next we take that filtered list and iterate it grabbing the `name` then we do a select of any elements which match that `name` and set the disabled property.

This could be simplified a few ways, one way is you could wrap a `fieldset` around each group and just set that to disabled.

Below is vanilla JS but should be adaptable to jQuery if necessary.

```js
    const groups =  document.querySelectorAll("#divFood input[type=radio]");
  [...groups].filter(input => input.checked)
    .forEach(input => [...document.querySelectorAll(`input[name=${input.name}]`)]
        .forEach(el => el.disabled = true)
  );
```

```html
<div id="divFood">
  <input id="chicken" type="radio" name="Meat" value="chicken" />
  <label for="chicken">chicken</label>
  <br />
  <input id="fish" type="radio" name="Meat" value="fish" />
  <label for="fish">fish</label>
  <br />
  <input id="beef" type="radio" name="Meat" value="beef" checked/>
  <label for="beef">beef</label>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input id="beans" type="radio" name="vegitables" value="beans" />
  <label for="beans">beans</label>
  <br />
  <input id="lettuce" type="radio" name="vegitables" value="lettuce" />
  <label for="lettuce">lettuce</label>
  <br />
  <input id="tomatos" type="radio" name="vegitables" value="tomatos"/>
  <label for="tomatos">tomatos</label>
  <br />
</div>
```